# HTML5 video events not triggered on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube-api, html5-video, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using YouTube iframe API inside iOS, I want to get notified when a video is going to start, here are my js codes, it works fine on desktop safari, but not inside iOS

```
<html>

<body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ytplayer;

    function getVideoElement() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('playerId');
        var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var vlist = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName('video');
        return vlist[0];
    }

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        ytplayer = new YT.Player('playerId', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        })
    }

    function onPlayerReady(a) {
        var v = getVideoElement();
        v.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
            alert('play');
        }, false);
        a.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(a) {
        return;
    }
</script>
<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='320' height='240' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ou6_MkIvKOo?enablejsapi=1&rel=1&egm=1&playsinline=1&autoplay=1&showinfo=0' frameborder='0'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're getting this to work in desktop Safari, either -- the `alert` function inside the `loadstart` event handler should never be triggered, because the browser ought to throw a security error when you try to access the contentDocument property of the iFrame (that's only allowed when both the parent and the iframe's source are on the same domain). iOS Safari is most likely honoring the security spec by not letting you inspect the contents of an iframe source that's in a different domain.

In any case, the API method for getting a notification when a video is about to play is to use the provided `onStateChange` callback. The YouTube player states that are closest to the HTML5 video's `loadstart`  would be buffering (when it starts loading the video) or cued ... so this function could be something like this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(a) {
        if (a.data==YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) { // or YT.PlayerState.CUED
          alert('play');
        }
    }
```

Of course, all of this is moot given that, on iOS, you can't autostart a video (with the parameter on the iframe embed or with the autostart playerVar in the API call) -- iOS doesn't allow programmatic playing of media but instead requires user intervention in all cases.